# How to use some class in mx ,spark libary in Flash professional CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-cs5, flex-spark

I used some class belong to mx and spark libary, but when I try to import them compiler throws an error `Library not found.`

```
Definition mx.controls:VideoDisplay could not be found.
Definition mx.core:UIComponent could not be found.
```

How can I import it to my project?

Answer (score 2):

You must set the path to packages in `Edit-> Preferences(Ctrl+U) -> ActionScript -> Actionscript3.0 settings.`
The path must point to package but not include it.